# Why does testthat 2.3.2 use a different sort()

Tags: r, testthat

(This question is also asked at Github [here](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/1181))

After an upgrade of R to 4.0.2 tests fail because it seems, the algorithm of `sort` in `testthat` changed. The following shows, that `base::sort()` and `browser()` are fine in R 4.0.2 (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63278404/5784831) question, why this check is added.):

```
y <- c("Schaffhausen", "Schwyz", "Seespital", "SRZ")
print(sort(y))
# [1] "Schaffhausen" "Schwyz"       "Seespital"    "SRZ"
browser()
print(sort(y))
# [1] "Schaffhausen" "Schwyz"       "Seespital"    "SRZ"
```

But if you create a package, call it `testsort`, add test-environment using `usethis::use_testthat()` and add a file "test-sort.R" in `/testsort/tests/testthat/`

```
test_that("test sort", {
  xx <- c("Schaffhausen", "Schwyz", "Seespital", "SRZ")
  print("")
  # bowser()
  print(sort(xx))
  expect_equal(sort(xx), c("Schaffhausen", "Schwyz", "Seespital", "SRZ"))
})
```

you get

```
==> devtools::test()

Loading testsort
Testing testsort
v |  OK F W S | Context
/ |   0       | sort[1] ""
[1] "SRZ"          "Schaffhausen" "Schwyz"       "Seespital"   
v |   1       | sort

== Results =============================================================================
OK:       1
Failed:   0
Warnings: 0
Skipped:  0
```

I used `debug(sort)` and `devtools::test()` in the RStudio console(!) but was not able to figure out what happens.

```
R.version
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2020                        
month          06                          
day            22                          
svn rev        78730                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
nickname       Taking Off Again
```

At present, `testthat` 2.3.2 is up to date, that is there is no newer version of testthat.

Thanks to @Ulugbek Umirov from [test](https://r-pkgs.org/tests.html):

> 10.5 CRAN notes
>
> CRAN will run your tests on all CRAN platforms: Windows, Mac, Linux
> and Solaris. There are a few things to bear in mind:
>
> Note that tests are always run in the English language (LANGUAGE=EN)
> and with C sort order (LC_COLLATE=C). This minimises
> spurious differences between platforms.

Comment: According to https://r-pkgs.org/tests.html - tests run with C sort order (LC_COLLATE=C) - which means that A-Z comes before a-z, thus it is expected to have SRZ in the beginning of the sorted list. Also this topic discusses breaking change in default behavior: https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/base-order-breaking-change-in-R-devel-td4763492.html

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov So according to nabble post, I would consider the `test` behaviour as a bug, because everything is correct in R 4.0.2? But thanks for your comment, with my very limited knowledge about encoding, this seems to explain everything.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov If I understand correctly, testthat now uses `withr::local_collate("C", .local_envir = .env)`. Furthernmore, this [commit](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/commit/25fb3485e5292002ffb44fa12bf43931769db872) caused the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-platform reproducibility is more imprtant. Setting the collation to `C` makes sure, tests give the same result across all platforms.

---

**Options to deal with this change if `sort` caused the problems** (sort depends on the collation)** you have at least 3 different options:

1. The use of `stringr::sort()`: New dependence on `stringr` package
2. Customize your function without additional packages

   ```
   myfun <- function(my_collation = "German_Switzerland.1252", ...) {
     my_locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")
     on.exit(expr = Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", my_locale))

     Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", my_collation)
     r <- sort(...)
     return(r)
   }
   ```

   No new packages are used thanks to `on.exit()`
3. Use of `withr-Package`which takes care of the `on.exit` part

   ```
   myfun <- function(my_collation = "German_Switzerland.1252", …) {
     withr::local_collate(my_collation)

     r <- sort(…)
     return(r)
   }
   ```

Comment: There is one bracket too much in `my_locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE"))` :)