# How to change LC_COLLATE=C globally for all tests in testhat?

Tags: r, testthat

Added some time later: we now choose to option 2 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63934762/5784831) instead of changing the test. Looking back, cross-platform reproducibility is more important ;-)

---

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63336729/5784831), the sort logics changed. My question is, how I could make the following test pass on a `LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252`?

Reproducible example: create a package, call it testsort, add test-environment using `usethis::use_testthat()` and add a file "test-sort.R" in `/testsort/tests/testthat/`

```
test_that("test sort", {
  xx <- c("Schaffhausen", "Schwyz", "Seespital", "SRZ")
  expect_equal(sort(xx), c("Schaffhausen", "Schwyz", "Seespital", "SRZ")) # fails with new sort
})
```

Backround: We have many projects where we always work on `LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252` and do sorting / comparing of German names, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39632751/5784831).
In our logics "R" is after "c" and we would like to test,
what we have / expect in our projects, thus the question. Furthermore, we would like to minimize dependencies on other package, e.g. avoid the use of `stringr::str_sort(, locale = ...)`, if possible.

---

It seems the crucial part happens only, when `testthat`/ `testthat::test_dir` is called:

```
withr::with_collate("C", # new code
                    withr::with_options(c(useFancyQuotes = FALSE), # new code
                                        withr::with_envvar(c(r_env_vars(), TESTTHAT_PKG = pkg$package), # code
                                                           do.call(testthat::test_dir, testthat_args))))
```

From the docs:

> Temporarily change collation order by changing the value of the LC_COLLATE locale.
> Usage with_collate(new, code)
>
> Temporarily change global options.
> Usage with_options(new, code)
>
> Temporarily change system environment variables.
> Usage with_envvar(new, code, action = "replace")

Comment: Why does this question get a downvote without a comment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the locale of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r)

Comment: @mnist I was asking about the specific context of testthat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
test_that("test sort", {
  # capture current locale
  locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")

  # set desired locale for test (eg English)
  if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
    invisible(Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "English")) 
  } else {
    invisible(Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "en_US.UTF-8")) 
  }
  
  # run test 
  xx <- c("Schaffhausen", "Schwyz", "Seespital", "SRZ")
  expect_equal(sort(xx), c("Schaffhausen", "Schwyz", "Seespital", "SRZ")) 

  # return to original locale  
  invisible(Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", locale))
})
```

Comment: Then I have to change the setting in each test. I thought, I can use the `helper` file to save typing, but this won't work, if understand correctly (see my edit). Do you understand, why they changed the test in a way, a behaviour is used within `testthat` that is NOT used in normal operation mode?