# How should I upgrade R properly to keep older versions running [Windows]?

Tags: r, windows

I more or less follow [this](https://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/) guideline:

1. Run `installr::updater()` from `../R-4.0.0/bin/x64/Rgui.exe` (as suggested if you run it from RStudio)
2. Update all packages (check the "update all packages" box from `installr::updater()`)
3. Change Windows system environment variable `R_LIBS` in my case to `..\R\R-4.0.x\library`.

If I want to switch the R vesion from RStudio, I need to

1. Set `Tools -> Global Options -> General -> R version` AND
2. change `R_LIBS` to the correct place. (If you forget this, `.libPaths()` has more than one entry.)

So my questions are:

- Is that process correct? Do I miss anything?
- What about changing `Rtools` when switching between major R-versions, see e.g. [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html)?
- It seems `installr::updater()` does not update the packages, although I check the "update all packages" box. (We observed that behaviour on two different laptops.)
- It seems, `.Rprofile`, `.Renviron`, and `Rprofile.site` play a crucial role, see [RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf). Last time, everything worked fine, `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron` were empty and I had to **add the line `.libPaths("path2/R-4.0.4/library")` to `Rprofile.site`**. It seems you can use `usethis::edit_r_profile()` to finde those files.

**Background**: I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63278404/5784831) question which was reproducible before I upgraded R to 4.0.2, but I realized, that after switching between
R `3.5.1`, `4.0.0` and `4.0.2` back and forth for testing it is not reproducible anymore.
Thus I think, that my update-process was error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two years later, I more or less follow [this](https://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/) process with success:
(**Windows**: Make sure R and RStudio are located `C:\`. Otherwise you run in trouble with `.libPaths()`!)

1. Run installr::updater() from `C:/R-4.x.y/bin/x64/Rgui.exe` (as suggested if you run it from RStudio)
2. Update Windows PATH variables
3. Update all packages (check the "update all packages" box from installr::updater())
4. Keep packages at the old R-version if you like

If you follow this process, `R_LIBS`, `.Rprofile`, and `.Renviron` should have no impact (it seems).